# Error while installing Remarkable Editor

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, editor, webkit, markdown

I downloaded the .deb file of Remarkable Markdown editor in Ubuntu 20.04. As soon as I started to run the .deb file, it is showing the following error:

> **Error: Dependency is not satisfiable: gir1.2-webkit-3.0**

As far as I know, WebKit is a browser engine for Apple Products. I do not know why it is required on Linux. Any help in resolving this will be very much appreciated.

Comment: The package is **not** apple specific; apple just use it. But if you look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gir1.2-webkit-3.0&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all you'll note it's *deprecated* and out-of-date. Refer https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gir1.2-webkit&searchon=names

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can run `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to install all the dependencies after installing the deb package.

Comment: Based on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jamiemcg/Remarkable/issues/379), the project seems pretty much abandoned. The developer is not even doing anything with the multiple fixes that people have offered 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still install Remarkable on Ubuntu [from Snap](https://snapcraft.io/remarkable) by using command below:

```
snap install remarkable
```

But better way is to use its modern and mature alternative named [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project/retext). It is installable [from official repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=retext&searchon=names) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install retext
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/seiferteric/remarkable_debfix) is a fix for installing **`Remarkable 1.87`** with `.deb` file format that worked for me and [others](https://github.com/jamiemcg/Remarkable/issues/371).

although I recommend install it via `gdebi` instead of `dpkeg -i` by this command

`sudo gdebi <your deb file.deb>`

for `remarkable` use this:

`sudo gdebi remarkable_1.18_.deb`

**Note**:
if you don't have `gdebi` install it :

`sudo apt install gdei`

Hope this helps others